# adding watch for an editable row in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, watch, x-editable

I am using xeditable for editing a table row in angular js. HTML Code is shown below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in viewModel.expenses">
<td>{{expense.eid}}</td>
<td><span editable-text="expense.billAmt" e-ng-model="editForm.billAmt" e-name="billAmt" e-form="rowform">{{expense.billAmt}}</span></td>
<td><span ng-show="!rowform.$visible">{{expense.split}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-control input-sm" e-ng-model="editForm.split" ng-disabled="true" /></td>
```

I want to update the 'split' value in last column when the value in 'billAmt' changes. So I add a watch in angularjs but is not updating.

```
$scope.$watch('editForm.billAmt',function(newValue,oldValue) {
    $scope.editForm.split=newValue/$scope.viewModel.members.length;
});
```

Is there any other way to add a watch while using xeditable?? How can I solve this?

Comment: Try applying $scope.$apply(); after updating the editForm.split value

Comment: @Hurix what is need to run digest cycle..as its already run after watch function completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd refrain from using `$scope.$watch()` and turn to a more efficient solution. You can use the `e-ng-change` directive to fire a function computing new value of `$scope.editForm.split` every time the `billAmt` value changes. It would look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in viewModel.expenses">
<td>{{expense.eid}}</td>
<td><span editable-text="expense.billAmt" e-ng-model="editForm.billAmt" e-name="billAmt" e-form="rowform" e-ng-change="checkSplit();">{{expense.billAmt}}</span></td>
<td><span ng-show="!rowform.$visible">{{expense.split}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-control input-sm" e-ng-model="editForm.split" ng-disabled="true" /></td>
```

And in your controller add function `checkSplit()`:

```
$scope.checkSplit = function(){
    $scope.editForm.split = $scope.editForm.billAmt / $scope.viewModel.members.length;
}
```

The `checkSplit()` function is invoked explicitly in a response to a event of value change, whereas `$scope.$watch()` handler runs on every digest cycle, so you can technically save some performance too.

Comment: `$scope.editForm = {};
 
 $scope.updateSplit = function(){
  console.log($scope.editForm.billAmt);
  console.log($scope.editForm.split);
  $scope.editForm.split = $scope.editForm.billAmt / $scope.viewModel.members.length;
  console.log($scope.editForm.split);
 }`   But the values are undefined.

Comment: Now I am able to get the values using the code  `$scope.updateSplit = function(self){
  $scope.editForm.split = self.$data / $scope.viewModel.members.length;
  //console.log($scope.editForm.split);
 }`  But the value of split doesnt get updated in view.